# Difference between Data.ByteString and Data.ByteString.Char8

Tags: haskell, bytestring

I read that Char8 only supports ASCII characters and will be dangerous to use if you are using other Unicode characters

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

--import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BC
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as E
import qualified Data.Text as T

name :: T.Text
name = "{ \"name\": \"哈时刻\" }"

nameB :: BC.ByteString
nameB = E.encodeUtf8 name

main :: IO ()
main = do
  BC.writeFile "test.json" nameB
  putStrLn "done"
```

produces the same result as

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
--import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BC
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as E
import qualified Data.Text as T

name :: T.Text
name = "{ \"name\": \"哈时刻\" }"

nameB :: B.ByteString
nameB = E.encodeUtf8 name

main :: IO ()
main = do
  B.writeFile "test.json" nameB
  putStrLn "done"
```

So what is the difference of using `Data.ByteString.Char8` vs `Data.ByteString`

Comment: Notice your two programs are actually identical.  The type `BC.ByteString` is a re-export of `Data.ByteString.ByteString` which you use as `B.ByteString` - so these are literally referring to the same type and all the code is identical so...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you compare `Data.ByteString` and `Data.ByteString.Char8`, you'll notice that a bunch of functions that reference `Word8` in the former reference `Char` in the latter.

```
-- Data.ByteString
map :: (Word8 -> Word8) -> ByteString -> ByteString
cons :: Word8 -> ByteString -> ByteString
snoc :: ByteString -> Word8 -> ByteString
head :: ByteString -> Word8
uncons :: ByteString -> Maybe (Word8, ByteString) 
{- and so on... -}


-- Data.ByteString.Char8
map :: (Char -> Char) -> ByteString -> ByteString
cons :: Char -> ByteString -> ByteString
snoc :: ByteString -> Char -> ByteString
head :: ByteString -> Char
uncons :: ByteString -> Maybe (Char, ByteString) 
{- and so on... -}
```

For these functions, and these functions only, `Data.ByteString.Char8` is providing the convenience of not have to constantly convert `Word8` values into and out of `Char` ones. **`writeFile` does exactly the same thing in both modules.**

Here is a nice way of seeing the different behaviours of similar functions in `Text`, `ByteString`, and `ByteString.Char8`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text.Encoding

import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BC

nameText :: T.Text
nameText = "哈时刻"

nameByteString :: B.ByteString
nameByteString = encodeUtf8 nameText

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ T.head nameText               -- '\21704'     actual first character
  print $ B.head nameByteString         -- 229          first byte
  print $ BC.head nameByteString        -- '\299'       first byte as character

  putStrLn [ T.head nameText ]          -- 哈           actual first character
  putStrLn [ BC.head nameByteString ]   -- å            first byte as character
```

Comment: Thank you so much for spending time to show me the differences. It seems that we should stick to `T.Text` if we do not want to lose the context of unicode characters. So what is the use case of `ByteString` then?

Comment: @laiboonh `ByteString` is for (surprise!) strings of bytes. Operations like file reads/writes, network communication, most cryptographic operations, and so on are typically most naturally represented in terms of `ByteString`. Operations on text -- like preparing HTML for a web page, modifying text documents, build UI -- should use `Text`. Occasionally it is necessary to convert between the two, e.g. to send some of your HTML along the network or to display your UI on stdout; in such cases you must choose an encoding to convert correctly.

Comment: @laiboonh `ByteString` is for raw binary data. `Text` is for... well... text. It depends on whether you're trying to deal with textual data, or just raw binary files / network protocols / etc.